# Setting Up Automated Offline Back-Up

Tags: server, ssh, backup, offline

I am going to be running an Ubuntu Server. The server itself will be hosted at a co-location data center.
I know how to access it remotely via SSH but I also want to set up a 2nd machine at my business HQ for offline backup.
I want this machine to backup often at certain times that I can choose (this time will be the time when I have the least amount of users).

How would I go about setting this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rsync setup on a cron job would work well for this. Google each for specific details on how to set them up.

Comment: Can you add some links? I understand that this question is a little vague, but it'd be helpful to have some links/instructions with a little more detail than "Google it".

Comment: What information would help this question become less vague.

Comment: I'm not sure why someone downvoted this answer. It's one quite possible way to accomplish what the OP wants. I would, of course, use rsync through an SSH tunnel. And links are good, but not necessary. `man rsync`, `man 5 crontab`, and `man ssh` are all you really need. (Of course, if someone knows any good links, they'd also be helpful).